# Unable to sort the X axis in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am unable to sort the x axis in ascending order. I tried using below mentioned code but it doesn't work. How can I order the x axis in ascending order?

```
mydata$Quarter <- reorder(mydata$Quarter, mydata$Fund)
ggplot(data=mydata1,aes(Quarter))+
  geom_point(aes(x = Quarter, y = Ratio, color = Fund))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 65, hjust = 1))
```

Comment: can you supply your data `mydata` by typing `dput(mydata)` into the console and adding the output to your question?

Comment: > dput(mydata)
structure(list(Fund = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c(" Fund XI-A, L.P.", 
"Opportunity Fund, LP"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(1:2, .Label = c("2013-Q3", 
"2017-Q1"), class = "factor"), Quarter = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Q1", 
"Q12"), class = "factor"), Commitment = structure(1:2, .Label = c("$20,000,000", 
"$35,000,000"), class = "factor"), NAV = structure(1:2, .Label = c("$247,764", 
"$40,888,084"), class = "factor"), Ratio = c(0.01, 1.17)), .Names = c("Fund", 
"Date", "Quarter", "Commitment", "NAV", "Ratio"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

Comment: what @brettljausn means is a small sample of your data `mydata`. So we can run your code..

Comment: You are using `mydata` and then `mydata1` within `ggplot` command. Not sure if `reorder(mydata$Quarter, mydata$Fund)` works. You need to use `reorder(mydata$Quarter, v)`, where `v` is the order you want to see on your x axis.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to find a way to reorder your factor variable `Quarter`, before you plot the data points. This should help:

```
library(ggplot2)

# example data
df = structure(list(Fund = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c(" Fund XI-A, L.P.", "Opportunity Fund, LP"), class = "factor"), 
                    Date = structure(1:2, .Label = c("2013-Q3", "2017-Q1"), class = "factor"), 
                    Quarter = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Q1", "Q12"), class = "factor"), 
                    Commitment = structure(1:2, .Label = c("$20,000,000", "$35,000,000"), class = "factor"), 
                    NAV = structure(1:2, .Label = c("$247,764", "$40,888,084"), class = "factor"), 
                    Ratio = c(0.01, 1.17)), .Names = c("Fund", "Date", "Quarter", "Commitment", "NAV", "Ratio"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

# keep the order of your factor variable as it is
ggplot(data=df,aes(Quarter))+
  geom_point(aes(x = Quarter, y = Ratio, color = Fund))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 65, hjust = 1))

# change the order and plot again
df$Quarter <- reorder(df$Quarter, 2:1)

ggplot(data=df,aes(Quarter))+
  geom_point(aes(x = Quarter, y = Ratio, color = Fund))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 65, hjust = 1))
```

As a more general solution (i.e. when you don't have only 2 factor levels) you can use `df$Quarter <- reorder(df$Quarter, length(df$Quarter):1)` to reorder.